# Color macro using Hex in Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the following code at the moment:

```
Function InteriorColor(CellColor As Range)
Application.Volatile
InteriorColor = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function

Sub Fillcolor()

For Each cl In [A3:D103]
    If cl.Value <> "" Then
    x = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl.Value, Range("L1:M50"), 2, 0)
    cl.Interior.ColorIndex = x
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

This code works on certain color codes (from the color palette) cell L1 -M50.

Yet i want to change it based on Hex or RGB values in a certain cell. Problem is i cant quite figure out how.

Comment: What can you not figure out? The HEX values and their equivalent colors? Or how to use them with the code?

Comment: For Hex or RGB colors try using Color instead of ColorIndex, you can then enter a hex code or use RGB(x,y,z)

Comment: @ PaulFrancis,How to use them with code. @ aebailey: When i change the ColorIndex to color, i do get a color but not the right one. As soon as i enter a Hex number like #99FF66 it doesn't work and it stays blank

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will return the color of a cell in various formats:

1. ColorIndex
2. Color
3. Hex
4. RGB

   ```
   Public Function RetrieveColor(rI As Range, Opt As Integer) As String
   Dim r As Range
   Set r = rI(1)
   Select Case Opt
       Case 1
           RetrieveColor = CStr(r.Interior.ColorIndex)
       Case 2
           RetrieveColor = CStr(r.Interior.Color)
       Case 3
           RetrieveColor = CStr(Hex(r.Interior.Color))
       Case 4
           v = r.Interior.Color
           h = Hex(v)
           nB = CStr(CLng("&H" & Mid(h, 1, 2)))
           nG = CStr(CLng("&H" & Mid(h, 3, 2)))
           nR = CStr(CLng("&H" & Mid(h, 5, 2)))
           RetrieveColor = nR & "," & nG & "," & nB
   End Select
   End Function
   ```

Comment: Cant quite fit this in my own code. My code looks at a certain name and matches this name with a color code from another column.

Comment: @user3084175 If you feel my post is of no value, I will delete it.

Comment: Im not saying it isn't of any value. Im just saying i cant get this  to fit in my existing code.

Comment: @user3084175  Update your Post to indicate the logic you need.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by changing Interior.ColorIndex to Interior.Color. With thanks to aebailey.
After that i could use the RGBint as a colorcode and it works ;)